# How do I seek the latest frame from an ongoing livestream on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

Currently I'm trying to retrieve the latest frame of an ongoing live-stream on YouTube, but have no idea how to do this.

The best I've managed to do on my own is making a GET request to:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key=${apiKey}`, but doesn't seem to return anything useful to me.

Using my browser's Developer Tools I have noticed YouTube makes a GET request to `https://rr3---sn-5hnednss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback` for what I think is exactly what I need though: The latest frame of the ongoing livestream.

Problem is, I have no idea how to use that endpoint and can't seem to find documentation on it online.

Does anyone know where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) and [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) you can get the last frame of a YouTube video by executing:

```bash
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i "$(yt-dlp -g VIDEO_ID | head -n 1)" -update 1 last.jpg
```

> This will seek to the last three seconds of the input and output all frames. But since `-update 1` is set, each frame will be overwritten to the same file, leaving only the last frame remaining.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/1448673)

> `yt-dlp -g VIDEO_ID | head -n 1` will retrieve the actual video URL from Google servers.

You may test with this already broadcasted YouTube live video id [RGBK6aHC9Yg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGBK6aHC9Yg) as the last frame is *interesting* by being black with some text unlike last seconds.

For an ongoing livestream, you can retrieve the first receive frame by executing:

```bash
ffmpeg -i "$(yt-dlp -g VIDEO_ID | head -n 1)" -vframes 1 last.jpg
```

As far as I tested with [vKVBgsOj2pc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKVBgsOj2pc), the retrieved frame is 10 seconds later than the date displayed on the livestream.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems to have worked with the example you provided, but unfortunately this command takes forever when I try it with the livestream I'm trying to seek the latest frame from, probably due to its enormous length.

Any way I can have it seek the latest frame directly instead of starting at frame 0?

Comment: Correction: Sorry, my bad, I didn't realize it was already doing that, it just kept on updating as the stream never ended. I'll give you your reward when I can.

Comment: Don't hesitate to share the livestream video id to let people be able to try with it.

Comment: `vKVBgsOj2pc`, it's an 24/7 livestream of 2 axolotls.

Comment: I modified my answer for being compatible with ongoing livestreams.

Comment: A few seconds of delay is fine, here's your +50 reputation.